# Nonlinear Robin boundary condition involving square root

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

If you have a nonlinear second-order boundary value problem where the domain of the problem is $x \in [a,b]$, the boundary conditions imposed are the Robins condition at $x=a$ and the Dirichlet condition at $x=b$, we can use the finite difference method to solve this. For example,

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2z}{dx^2} = f(z,z',x)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
c_1 z'(a) + c_2 z(a) = c_3
\end{equation}

In terms of finite differences (central for the interior and forward for the left boundary) where the grid points are $i=1 , \dots, n$ and the step size is $h$.

The governing equation is,

\begin{equation}
\frac{z_{i + 1} - 2 z_i + z_{i - 1}}{h^2} = f\left(z_i,\left(\frac{z_{i + 1} - z_{i - 1}}{2 h} \right),x_i\right) \quad i=2,\dots,n-1
\end{equation}

The solution $z(x)$ should satisfy the governing equation but it should also satisfy the boundary conditions. So, we need to write down a difference equation at the boundary $x=a$ that satisfies *both* the boundary conditions and the governing equation.

Taylor expanding $z_2$ and $z_3$ at the point $z_1$,

\begin{align}
& z_2 = z_1 + \frac{dz}{dx}\Bigg|_{i=1} h + \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}\Bigg|_{i=1} \frac{h^2}{2!} + \ldots \\
& z_3 = z_1 + \frac{dz}{dx}\Bigg|_{i=1} (2h) + \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}\Bigg|_{i=1} \frac{4h^2}{2!} + \ldots
\end{align}

we have,

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}\Bigg|_{i=1} = \frac{-z_3 + 8 z_2 - 7z_1 - 6 h \frac{dz}{dx}\Big|_{i=1}}{2 h^2}
\end{equation}

From the Robins condition,

\begin{equation}
\frac{dz}{dx}\Big|_{i=1} = \frac{c_3 - c_2 z_1}{c_1}
\end{equation}

the governing equation at $i=1$ is,

\begin{align}
& \frac{d^2z}{dx^2}\Bigg|_{i=1} = f\left(z_1,\frac{dz}{dx}\Big|_{i=1},x_1\right)
\end{align}

Thus,

\begin{equation}
\frac{-z_3 + 8 z_2 - 7z_1 - 6 h \frac{c_3 - c_2 z_1}{c_1}}{2 h^2} = f\left(z_1,\frac{c_3 - c_2 z_1}{c_1},x_1\right)
\end{equation}

Assuming $f$ is not very complicated, i.e. it could be nonlinear but not anything complicated, say a polynomial, then you could collect like terms and maybe have a few nonlinear polynomial terms.

---

In my situation, the nonlinear second order boundary value differential equation is

\begin{equation}
z''(x)-\frac{\frac{1}{100} z(x)^4 \left(2 z'(x)^2+12\right)-600 \left(z'(x)^2+1\right)-\frac{3 z(x)^8}{500000}}{20 z(x) \left(10-\frac{z(x)^4}{1000}\right)}=0
\end{equation}

I have a nonlinear Robins boundary condition at $x=a$.
\begin{equation}
z'(a) + (d-1) \left(1-\left(\frac{z(a)}{z_h}\right)^{d+1}\right) \sqrt{1+\frac{z'(a)^2}{1-\left(\frac{z(a)}{z_h}\right)^{d+1}}}=0
\end{equation}

where $d=3$, $z_h=10$, and $x\in [10^{-8},10^{-1}]$. Also, the Dirichlet condition at $b=10^{-1}$ is $z(b) = 10^{-3}$. $\textbf{TAKE NOTE:}\; z(a) < z_h = 10$

Discretizing the ODE, we have the governing equation for $i = 2, \ldots, n-1$

\begin{equation}
\frac{z_{i + 1} - 2 z_i + z_{i - 1}}{h^2}-\frac{\frac{1}{100} z_i^4 \left(2 \left(\frac{z_{i + 1} - z_{i - 1}}{2 h} \right)^2+12\right)-600 \left(\left(\frac{z_{i + 1} - z_{i - 1}}{2 h} \right)^2+1\right)-\frac{3 z_i^8}{500000}}{20 z_i \left(10-\frac{z_i^4}{1000}\right)}=0
\end{equation}

I have tried discretizing the Robins boundary conditions in the same way as above, i.e. by isolating $z'(a)$, but I'm getting solutions that are doubtful to be correct. So, should I do anything here before doing the finite difference? In particular, I'm thinking the square root is causing some issues. Any guidance on this or suggestion if it does not differ from usual methods?

My code is written in Mathematica below,

```
(*Setup the equation*)
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
f = 1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1);
L = (Sqrt[1 + (z'[x]^2/f)]/z[x]^d) + (d - 1) (z'[x]/z[x]^d);(*Lagrangian*)
eulageq = EulerEquations[L, z[x], x];(*Euler-Lagrange equation*)
s = Solve[eulageq, z''[x]][[1]] // Simplify;
eq = z''[x] - s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10};(*governing equation displayed in post, s[[1,2]] is like the f(z,z',x) in the post*)
bc = z'[x] + (d - 1) (1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1)) Sqrt[1 + (z'[x]^2/(1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1)))];(*Robins condition displayed in post*)

(*Setting up the finite difference and residuals*)
n = 1000;(*Grid points*)
h = (b - a)/(n - 1);(*Step size*)
a = 10^-8;(*a & b are the domain*)
b = 10^-1;
zf = 10^-3;(*zf is the Dirichlet condition at x=b*)
zp = -Sqrt[((d - 1)^2 (1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1))^2)/(1 - (d - 1)^2 (1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1)))] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10, z[x] -> z[1]};(*zp is the z'[a] solved from the boundary conditions bc*)
rule = Table[{z''[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - 2 z[i] + z[i - 1])/h^2), z'[x] -> ((z[i + 1] - z[i - 1])/(2 h)), z[x] -> z[i]}, {i, 2, n - 1}];(*finite difference rule*)
eqs = Table[{eq} /. rule[[i]], {i, Length[rule]}];(*substitute the finite difference to the governing equation*)
residual = h^2 eqs // Flatten;(*residual of the governing equation*)
residbound = (-z[3] + 8 z[2] - 7 z[1] - 6 zp h) - 2 h^2 s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10, z[x] -> z[1], z'[x] -> zp};(*residual of the Robins condition, s[[1,2]] is like the f(z,z',x) in the post*)

(*Setup the sparse matrix*)
For[i = 2, i <= n - 1, i++, jac[i] = D[residual[[i - 1]], {{z[i - 1], z[i], z[i + 1]}}]]
DFx = Table[jac[i], {i, 2, n - 1}];
ShiftMatrix[mat_, shift_] := Reverse@PadLeft@MapThread[PadLeft[#1, Length[mat] + #2, 0, #2] &, {Reverse[mat], shift}]
jacbound = D[residbound, {{z[1], z[2], z[3]}}];
sparseresidual = ShiftMatrix[DFx, Table[i, {i, 0, n - 3}]][[All, n - 4 ;;]];
sparse = Join[{Join[jacbound, ConstantArray[0, n - 3]]}, sparseresidual, {Join[ConstantArray[0, n - 1], {1}]}];

m = 90;(*Number of iteration*)
zi = 9.5;(*Initial test point for z[1]*)
z0[0] = Join[{zi}, Reverse[Table[((zi - zf)/(b - a)) (i - a) + zf, {i, a + h, b - h, h}]], {zf}];(*Initial test points for the z[i]'s*)

(*Newton's method*)
For[j = 0, j <= m, j++, residuals = h^2 eqs;
DFxmat = sparse /. z[i_] :> z0[j][[I]];
Residvec = {residbound /. z[i_] :> z0[j][[i]], residuals /. z[i_] :> z0[j][[i]], 0} // Flatten; 
z0[j + 1] = z0[j] + 0.22 LinearSolve[N[DFxmat], N[-Residvec]] // Flatten] // AbsoluteTiming

(*Residual error*)
ResidTol = Total[Table[Abs[residuals[[i]]], {i, 1, n - 2}] /. z[i_] :> z0[j][[i]] // Flatten]/n;
Print["Residual Tolerance = ", ResidTol]

Residual Tolerance = 7.090653622*10^-14

range = Range[a, b, h];
list = MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {range, z0[j]}];
zapprox = Interpolation[list, InterpolationOrder -> 10, Method -> "Spline"];

zapprox[a]
9.999999722

zapprox'[a]
0.01664915436

zapprox''[a]
-498.9821196

(*Check if Robins boundary is satisfied, must be equal to 0*)
bc /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10, z[x] -> zapprox[a], z'[x] -> zapprox'[a]}
0.01666025571

(*Check if governing equation is satisfied, must be equal to 0*)
zapprox''[a] - s[[1, 2]] /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10, z[x] -> zapprox[a], z'[x] -> zapprox'[a]}
-0.003923034814

(*Using zapprox[a] in the Robins condition bc as a consistency check for zapprox'[a]*)
sol = (z' + (d - 1) (1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1)) Sqrt[1 + (z'^2/(1 - (z[x]/zh)^(d + 1)))]) /. {d -> 3, zh -> 10, z[x] -> zapprox[a]};

Solve[sol == 0, z']
z' -> -2.222100815*10^-7
```

As you see, the governing equation and boundary equation at $x=a$ is not 0. Also, the resulting `zapprox'(a)` is not consistent with the result given by the Robins condition `bc` if you plug in `zapprox(a)`.

Comment: You may simplify your problem in a first step and check if the checks are fullfilled pointwise, e.g. using two Dirichlet BC's and a linear right hand side. If this does not hold, then something else is wrong.

Comment: @ConvexHull Take note that $z(a) < z_h = 10$. Taking $z(a) \in (8, 9.999)$ would be reasonable.

Comment: As a total aside, it should be "Robin", not "Robins" -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Gustave_Robin

Comment: A "quick and dirty" approach is solving it by shooting, integrating the ODE from the end x=b where Dirichlet BC is set to the end x=a where the Robin BC is set. Probably something better than that can be proposed, if we know the strategy for integration in x. How would you solve this equation if Dirichlet BC were set on both ends?

Comment: It is  (also) a simple nonlinear 1D Poisson equation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is indeed a simple (yet nonlinear) 1D Poisson equation, and there are different possible approaches for solving it (Newton iterations, pseudo time stepping etc.) Once a preferred solution strategy is chosen (aside from the BC implementation), one can design an appropriate implementation of the BC.

Comment: @MaximUmansky I understand that shooting is another method, however, from the physical problems I'm encountering, it is better to use finite difference (FD) since I would like to iterate for several boundary points. In addition, I also encounter coupled nonlinear 2nd order ODEs which is much more complicated, and so I would like to employ FD here to assure that the method works at least in the simpler case as ConvexHull is saying.

Comment: @mathemania Shooting does not exclude finite difference. You could integrate the equation using finite difference but to resolve the mismatch in the boundary condition you'd need to tune up the derivative z' at x=b. It would boil down to solving a nonlinear equation (by Newton's method or something of that kind), but it would be a 1D nonlinear equation. What ConvexHull is proposing is certainly doable but it would lead to a nonlinear equation of higher dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem in more abstract way:

A **linear** approximation of the Poisson problem **including the Robin boundary conditions** can already be written as

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \vec{z} = \vec{f}.
\end{align}

Now in your case the right hand side depends on the solution itself making the problem **non-linear**

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \vec{z} = f(\vec{z}),
\end{align}

which can be written as **minimization** problem

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \vec{z} - f(\vec{z}) =: F(\vec{z}) \stackrel{!}{=} 0.
\end{align}

The problem can be tackled using the **Newton-Raphson** method

\begin{align}
\vec{z}^{k+1} =\vec{z}^{k} - \mathbf{J}(\vec{z}^k)^{-1} F(\vec{z}^k).
\end{align}

with the **Jacobian** matrix

\begin{align}
\mathbf J = \frac{\partial F_i}{\partial z_j}\longrightarrow\mathbf{A} - \text{diag} \left( \left. \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial z_i}\right|_{i=j}\right).
\end{align}

Instead of calculating $\mathbf{J}^{-1}$ you can solve this linear system

\begin{align}
\mathbf{J}(\vec{z}^k) \vec{b} = F(\vec{z}^k),
\end{align}

and update the solution iteratively with

\begin{align}
\vec{z}^{k+1} =\vec{z}^{k} - \vec{b}(\vec{z}^k).
\end{align}

Comment: That is exactly how I solved the problem (I added a Mathematica the code with comments),  however, I'm not sure if writing the Robins condition in the same way is correct, i.e. like the simpler setup I wrote at the start of my post.

Comment: Of course, your problem simply boils down to a linear discretization of the Poisson problem using Robin boundary conditions.

Comment: You mean it is correct to use the same way of discretizing as in the simpler setup that I wrote? But, in the last part of my code you can see that the solution I got doesn't really satisfy the governing equation and the boundary condition, i.e. it's not equal to 0.

Comment: I didn't say anything that $z(x=a) = 0$, what I'm saying is that looking at the Robins condition where all terms are on one side so that it is an equation (something = 0). I have written my code in such a way too so that if you check everything, the result should give 0 (of course machine precision zero), i.e. it satisfies the Robins condition.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. In general, the consistence checks should be fullfilled, pointwise (using a FD method). However, I am no Mathematica user, so I am not able to debug the code. I must think about it a bit.

Comment: I see, I filled the code with comments so that it'll be easier to read for non-Mathematica users. In any case, I did exactly what is in your post (it's in the `Newton's method` part of my code). I first set up the equations, then prepare the finite difference and the residuals which is the $b$ in $\textbf{A} \vec{z} = \vec{b}$ (and the partials of the residual is the Jacobian matrix $\textbf{A}$), then create the sparse matrix, then Newton's method.